# How to automatically resolve conflicts in bitbucket when multiple developers are working to merge changes to mainline

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I have the following situation:
There is a mainline branch in bitbucket. Every developer creates a branch out of this mainline and works on it. Once the developer finishes his code development in dev branch, he syncs code from mainline and runs a CI process to test if all is fine. Once the build passes (including the sanity tests), then the code from the dev branch is merged to the mainline.

**Problem Statement:**

1. Developer X creates a development branch called X_DEV from mainline (ML).
2. Once Developer X completes his development, he takes the latest code from the mainline ML and syncs it to his X_DEV branch.
3. Developer X runs build and sanity tests on his X_DEV branch. Then, after all the tests pass, he merges code to the mainline ML.
4. But when Developer X was running tests on his code in step 3, another developer named 'Y' created a new development branch called Y_DEV from the mainline.
5. After creating new development branch Y_DEV, the developer writes his code and tests it. After doing tests in his dev branch, he then copies the latest code from the mainline (at this time changes of developer X were not yet present in ML mainline).
6. After Developer Y copies the latest code from the mainline, he again runs build and sanity tests, after which he merges his code to the mainline. But his code fails to get merged to the mainline because new code was copied to the ML by Developer X, and that code was not yet present in branch Y_DEV. Due to this issue, developer Y wastes his time and has to again sync code from mainline and run build and sanity tests again.

How can we have an automatic and intelligent solution here?

**How to handle these issues without adding wait/sleep or waiting for X_Dev code to get synced to ML or having each functionality to have its own SDLC?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have an "*automatic*" solution to resolve your merge conflicts/issues. Git can help you manage your code, but you can't really teach it to resolve merge conflicts for you. Most of the time, you'll have to manually check and carefully resolve each conflict by yourself.

I think you're best solution here is to do some changes to your development process.

**First**, when you say "*syncs code from the mainline*" or "*copies code from the mainline*", I hope you mean either doing `git rebase master` or `git merge master` on the dev branch. If not, then I suggest you look into `git rebase`.

**Second**, how do you create your development branches? *Ideally*, each branch should be independent enough that work done on 1 branch (say X) does not conflict or depend on the work being done on other branches (Y, Z, etc.). Merge conflicts usually happen when the branches are touching the same part of the code/module/feature. If you can somehow isolate the code changes to be made into separate branches, then that would reduce chances for merge conflict.

In your sample scenario, it seems that Y's and X's work are closely related. Maybe they should just work on a single branch YX? So that running the tests will be done only once but will test both of their features at the same time. OR you could instead create an intermediate branch first (Z) where you dev the **common** changes for Y and X, then branch-off Y and X from Z. After X and Y are finished coding and testing, they merge their code back to Z. You do another set of tests on Z, then Z is merged back to the mainline. Since both X and Y have a copy of the common changes, it reduces the chances for conflicts when they merge their code to Z.

**Third**, you can have 2 kinds of testing: **Branch/Feature Testing** and **Integration Testing**.

**Branch Testing** is what you're already doing, running build and sanity tests on each feature branch before they're merged back to the mainline. That's great, because, from the point of view of the branch, it checks that the modified code did not break any other features.

**Integration Testing** (IT) is what you do when you merge the branches back to the mainline. It's the same build and sanity tests that you already do on each branch, but this time, **it's done on the mainline rather than on a branch** AND it checks that nothing broke when ALL the features were merged to the mainline. This allows each branch to be merged without requiring it to sync first with all the other branches. Based on your sample scenario, you're already doing IT but you're doing it on EACH branch, since you need each branch to get the changes first from other branches. Of course, it's still a good idea to do that, but with IT, you don't always need to. (Plus, IT is easier to automate, since you can ALWAYS have it running on the mainline.).

Hope that helps.